# To load a text file in text area on selection of a drop down option in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a drop down with 3 options as 
a
b
c

I want to load a local file in the text area on same page besides the drop down on selection of options.

For ex. When I click on option a, Content of a.txt should be displayed on the text area.

When I click on option b, Content of b.txt should be displayed on the text area.

Please help.

Comment: This is basic MVC application functionality.

Comment: Do you want to dynamically load what is inside of the text file on your computer and put it inside the textarea?

Do you only have client side code or do you also have server side code?

Comment: Yes, I want to load the content of text file dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that with javascript. To access the file system you need some server side language, like C# or PHP. There is the new file system API, but is only supported in modern browsers (HTML 5) which will limit your users using older versions of the protocol.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: It can be done very simply using Java on a JSP in an MVC-structured application.

Comment: Thank you.. But I want to use javascript only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HTML5 File system API for reading local files.

sample code:

```
  function readSingleFile(evt) {
    //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
    var f = evt.target.files[0]; 

    if (f) {
      var r = new FileReader();
      r.onload = function(e) { 
          var contents = e.target.result;
        alert( "Got the file.n" 
              +"name: " + f.name + "n"
              +"type: " + f.type + "n"
              +"size: " + f.size + " bytesn"
              + "starts with: " + contents.substr(1, contents.indexOf("n"))
        );  
      }
      r.readAsText(f);
    } else { 
      alert("Failed to load file");
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
```

More details are available here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=EF1E1e1JJgF

Comment: HTML5 File system API can only be used in Chrome and Opera, and has some pretty bad security vulnerabilities if not used for specific use-cases.  The time-tested method of approaching this would be to use Java on a JSP in an MVC-structured application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in browser on local filesystem - no chance. At least you have to run local web server.

On web server it would look alike this: http://webkurz.kvalitne.cz/pracovni_soubory/zima2013/ajax.html , only you can use jQuery get

Comment: Thank you.. Yes same thing I want to do.

Comment: Can you please tell how to do using jQuery get

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP in your script if you want (assuming the script is in a *.php* file)

```
<?php
    function readTextFile($file) {
        $myfile = fopen($file, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        return str_replace("'", '"', fread($myfile, filesize($file)));
        fclose($myfile);
    };
?>

var optionsObject = {
    a: '<?=readTextFile('/path/to/a.txt') ?>',
    b: '<?=readTextFile('/path/to/b.txt') ?>',
    c: '<?=readTextFile('/path/to/c.txt') ?>'
};
var optionsArray = [
    '<?=readTextFile('/path/to/a.txt') ?>',
    '<?=readTextFile('/path/to/b.txt') ?>',
    '<?=readTextFile('/path/to/c.txt') ?>'
];
```

The first JS variable (`optionsObject`), is an object.  To get the the text file from this variable, use `optionsObject.{abc}` (replace `{abc}` with either `a`, `b`, or `c`).

The second JS variable (`optionsArray`), is an array.  To get the the text file from this variable, use `optionsArray[{0-2}]` (replace `{0-2}` with either `0`, `1`, or `2`).

You could also use JavaScript's Ajax, but you are using `.txt` files, and to do that you have to add some extra code because most browsers cache text files and don't like to reread them.  PHP will always reread them, and won't cache text files the same way browsers do.